# How to cite a newspaper article with no author in APA style using MS Word?

Tags: citation-style

I have cited a news story appeared in a newspaper with no author in APA style using MS Word 2013, but I don't know if I have done it in the right way. I classified it as "Article in a Periodical", but the outcome is different from the one I get from this web service (https://www.citethisforme.com/). Can I help me in this case?

*MS Word version:*

In-text: (Zarif: We’ve never claimed nuclear deal only favors Iran, 2015, p. 1)

In Bibliography: Zarif: We’ve never claimed nuclear deal only favors Iran. (2015, July 22). Tehran TImes(12321), p. 1.

*Cite This For Me" version:*

In-text: (Tehran Times, 2015)

In Bibliography: Tehran Times,. (2015). Zarif: We’ve never claimed nuclear deal only favors Iran, p. 1.

I feel that MS Word's version is correct, but its in-text citation seems awkward to me.

Comment: I'm afraid that we are likely to be unable to help you without knowing what the two citations that you are considering actually look like, to know whether they are reasonable or unreasonable.  Can you please edit the information into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I must always advise that you speak to your professor and/or your university librarian as to what the accepted form would be at your University. Both as professors and Universities can vary slightly on the specifics of APA rules and due to the fact that what they say will be accepted. As far as APA 6th is concerned

> Title of article. (Year, month day). *Title of publication*, p. [or pp.]

So:

> Zarif: We’ve never claimed nuclear deal only favors Iran. (2015, July 22). *Tehran Times*, p. 1.

would be the correct Biblio (provided one correctly indents it).

While In-text

> "First few words of the title", year, p. [or pp.]

So: `("Zarif: We've never claimed", 2015, p.1)`

As confirmed [at the University of Melborune](http://www.lib.unimelb.edu.au/recite/citations/apa6/ref16-NewspaperNoAuthor.html), [EasyBib](http://www.easybib.com/reference/guide/apa/newspaper), and [APAstyle.org](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/web-page-no-author.aspx)

---

One of those variance, by college and professor, is in-text citations and the use of page numbers. As some schools only require one to [cite page numbers on direct quotes](http://libguides.css.edu/c.php?g=41681&p=265025) while others requires one [to add page numbers in all instances](http://www.lib.unimelb.edu.au/recite/citations/apa6/ref16-NewspaperNoAuthor.html)

Another variance is with online articles, as online articles may not reference a page number (depends on format) but use the paragraph number or section title in the citation. Further, you would include a "Retrieved from *full url here*" at the end. (pp.171-172, *APA Manual*, 6th ed.)

Comment: Great answer! One minor addition: If you read the newspaper article online, then (a)  you would not reference a page number, and (b) you would use "Retrieved from [URL]" in the reference (bibliography). Some publications or professors might want you to include both the print cite and the online cite.

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD added as another variance at end